# How to reinstall Scientific Linux remotely on distributed cluster

Tags: software-installation, scientific-linux

We are currently running SL5 and need to upgrade this to SL7 (latest release). Apparently this requires a clean install. I have limited access to the actual rack. I will attempt to do this all remotely if at all possible. I've already backed up all the important data.

Here is the setup:
1 gateway node
9 worker nodes

My first goal is to upgrade one of the worker nodes only. What exact steps do I need to take to get the process started and do this as efficiently as possible?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use a virtualization platform (KVM,VMWare,VirtualBox) to migrate a copy of the cluster into it. Maybe you don't need all Workers in it.Then play the update. Write down all the steps that are needed. You can use snapshot to restore and play it again if you ran into problems. After having a "run-book" you can make a final backup of production and run your update. No other can give you a bullet proofe check list to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was looking for more help on the technical side of things (i.e. what to do).

Comment: well but in the end we doing the update and not you, my friend :-) --> "We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.
Provide details. Share your research."  see also see http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask